# Ifelse in R or apply

Tags: r, if-statement

I am attempting to make elements in the first column of my df null (no entry at all) if it is equal to the element in the same row in the second column. This is a very simple thing, but I haven't been able to find the answer in the message boards.

Below are two of my attempts:

```
ifelse(y2014[y2014[,1]==y2014[,2]],y2014[,1]=="",y2014[,1]==y2014[,1])

y2014$new=ifelse(y2014[,1]==y2014[,2],0,y2014[,1])
```

Both give the following error: "level sets of factors are different" I checked the number of levels in each and they're equal, though several cells are blank in column 2. Would an apply function work better for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Really appreciate your help for a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things, factors generally need to be converted to character prior to comparing, and you want to assign `NA` rather than `0` to the value.

Something like this might be better:

```
y2014$new <- y2014[,1]
y2014$new[as.character(y2014$new) == as.character(y2014[,2])] <- NA
```